# Что устанавливается с .NET 4.0 Client Profile?

Tags: .net, c#

Если приложение .NET собирается под .NET 4.0 Client Profile, то что нужно будет установить на машину: только клиентский профиль или что-то еще? И как это пересекается с уже установленными на машину каркасами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потребуется установить только клиентский профиль.

Из [статьи](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc656912(VS.100).aspx) MSDN:

> Независимый компонент. Допускает отдельное обслуживание. Не требует платформу .NET Framework.